# Where did the Sailsjs websockets documentation go?

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js

If I try to look up the docs in google, I get to see this: broken link. Has Sails stopped the websockets support and if not: where can I find something like a docs/tutorial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets

Works pretty good for me. Just check out the link and go to documentation...

Comment: As you can see, they removed websockets from their documentation. sailsjs.org/#!documentation/sockets < this is the old link

Comment: http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets - sorry I should have been more specific

Comment: Thanks! I think they moved it and Google hasn't re-indexed it than.

Answer (score 1):

The Sails websocket framework is built on top of http://socket.io/. It provides a publish/subscribe protocol for your existing models.

So for example, to subscribe a client connected socket to all "create" and "destroy" events for a User model you would add the following to a controller.

```
   User.find({}).exec(function(e,listOfUsers){
       User.subscribe(req.socket,listOfUsers,['create','destroy']);
   });
```

Then on the client side you simply include the [sails.io](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js) script to allow the client to connect. If the above controller has a route applied to it such as /user/socket the client would simply do:

```
   io.socket.get('/user/socket', function (data, jwres){
      // do something if any data is returned
   });
```

Then the client could "subscribe" to the event:

```
   io.socket.on('user', function onServerSentEvent (msg) {
     // this event will fire any time the 'User.create' and 'User.destroy' event is called
   });
```

For those of you looking for this documentation that stumble across this thread and the above url isn't working, they moved it here (I think they added hash bang /#!/ to their site). The documentation does a better job of explaining it then I do.

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets

Comment: Please quote here some parts of the solution and don't give only a link